# List item intent not working in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview

i have made a simple android program for listview for learning purpose,In that i have taken alistview with a text and an image.now i want is when i click on item from list then it should come to next activity with that particular image and text..I have impelmented as below thats not working Please help me for the same:

**main**

```
package com.example.androidlistview;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     String[] smily = new String[]  {"Angry","Basic","Cool","Cry","Err","Evil","Kiss","Laugh","Shame"
                ,"Toungh","Wink","Wonder"};

        int[] pic =new int[]{
                R.drawable.ic_action_emo_angry,
                R.drawable.ic_action_emo_basic,
                R.drawable.ic_action_emo_cool,
                R.drawable.ic_action_emo_cry,
                R.drawable.ic_action_emo_err,
                R.drawable.ic_action_emo_evil,
                R.drawable.ic_action_emo_kiss,
                R.drawable.ic_action_emo_laugh,
                R.drawable.ic_action_emo_shame,
                R.drawable.ic_action_emo_tongue,
                R.drawable.ic_action_emo_wink,
                R.drawable.ic_action_emo_wonder

        };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

            for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
                hm.put("sml", " " + smily[i]);

                hm.put("pic", Integer.toString(pic[i]) );
                aList.add(hm);
            }
            String[] from = { "pic","sml" };


            int[] to = { R.id.smily,R.id.txt};


            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.list_layout, from, to);

            final ListView listView = ( ListView ) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Descripsn.class);
                        String smiley=(String)listView.getSelectedItem();
                        Bundle b =new Bundle();
                        intent.putExtra("smily", smiley);
                        intent.putExtra("image", smily[arg2]);
                        startActivity(intent);
                }

            });


    }



}
```

**desc.java**

```
package com.example.androidlistview;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Descripsn extends Activity {
TextView tv;
ImageView im;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_descripsn);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        im=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagedesc);

        Intent i =getIntent();
        Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
        String smily = b.getString("smiley");
        int img = b.getInt(smily);
        tv.setText(smily);
    }


}
```

**Log**

```
06-21 09:44:38.263: I/Choreographer(4029): Skipped 53 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-21 09:44:39.523: I/Choreographer(4029): Skipped 58 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-21 09:44:48.243: I/Choreographer(4029): Skipped 74 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-21 09:44:48.633: I/Choreographer(4029): Skipped 200 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-21 09:44:48.853: I/Choreographer(4029): Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-21 09:44:49.685: I/Choreographer(4029): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-21 09:44:54.079: I/Choreographer(4029): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-21 09:44:54.733: I/Choreographer(4029): Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: not working means not getting the text in next activity by intent

Comment: yep...text and image also not getting in next activity..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {

                 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Descripsn.class);

                    intent.putExtra("smily", smily[arg2].toString());
                    intent.putExtra("image", pic[arg2]);
                    intent.putExtra("pos", arg2);
                    startActivity(intent);
            }
```

and get in other activity

```
Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
    String smily = b.getString("smily");
    int img = b.getInt("image");
    int imgpos = b.getInt("pos");
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your Descripsn  class you must use the same identifier for getExtras..

try like this..

```
Intent i =getIntent();
        Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
        String smily = b.getString("smily");
        String img = b.getString("image");
        tv.setText(smily);
```

**EDIT:-**
you will get the text passed as you desired .. but for image, well you can send the selected list position as an identifier to your next intent like this..

```
 @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Descripsn.class);
                        String smiley=(String)listView.getSelectedItem();
                        Bundle b =new Bundle();
                        intent.putExtra("smily", smiley);
                        intent.putExtra("image", smily[arg2]);
                        intent.putExtra("pos", arg2);
                        startActivity(intent);
                }
```

and then get extras like this,,

```
Intent i =getIntent();
            Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
            String smily = b.getString("smily");
            String img = b.getString("image");
            int imgpos = b.getInt("pos");
            tv.setText(smily);
```

Comment: edited the post.. if still you facing the prob then try adding `Log` to print what values you getting after getExtras..

Answer (score 0):

```
String smily = b.getString("smiley");
```

Wrong))

try this:

```
String smily = b.getString("smily");
```

Answer (score 0):

**main.java**
 package com.example.androidlistview;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     String[] smily = new String[]  {"Angry","Basic","Cool","Cry","Err","Evil","Kiss","Laugh","Shame"
                ,"Toungh","Wink","Wonder"};

        public int[] pic =new int[]{
                R.drawable.ic_action_emo_angry,
                R.drawable.ic_action_emo_basic,
                R.drawable.ic_action_emo_cool,
                R.drawable.ic_action_emo_cry,
                R.drawable.ic_action_emo_err,
                R.drawable.ic_action_emo_evil,
                R.drawable.ic_action_emo_kiss,
                R.drawable.ic_action_emo_laugh,
                R.drawable.ic_action_emo_shame,
                R.drawable.ic_action_emo_tongue,
                R.drawable.ic_action_emo_wink,
                R.drawable.ic_action_emo_wonder

        };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

            for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
                hm.put("sml", " " + smily[i]);

                hm.put("pic", Integer.toString(pic[i]) );
                aList.add(hm);
            }
            String[] from = { "pic","sml" };


            int[] to = { R.id.smily,R.id.txt};


            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.list_layout, from, to);

            final ListView listView = ( ListView ) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Descripsn.class);
                    Bundle b =new Bundle();
                    intent.putExtra("smily", smily[arg2]);
                    intent.putExtra("image", pic[arg2]);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            });


    }



}
```

**desc.jav**

```
package com.example.androidlistview;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Descripsn extends Activity {
TextView tv;
ImageView im;
private MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_descripsn);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        im=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagedesc);

        Intent i =getIntent();
        Bundle b=  getIntent().getExtras();
        String smily = b.getString("smily");
       int img = b.getInt("image");
        String imgpos = b.getString("pos");

        System.out.println("Image value"+img);

        //System.out.println("======Posi::::::"+smily);

       tv.setText(smily);
       im.setBackgroundResource(img);
    }


}
```